# / gets remounted read-only, can't find original cause in dmesg because systemd spams it with "read-only" filesystem errors afterwards

Tags: ubuntu, dmesg

During normal use, my Ubuntu laptop intermittently will encounter some I/O error and then remount `/` as read-only (yes I've checked SMART logs, nothing shows up; I've also replaced the drive, no luck). The problem is I can never read the underlying original error (if any is reported) because the filesystem is remounted read-only by then, so the error doesn't get recorded to disk anywhere, and if I run `dmesg` the circular buffer has been fully spammed by other processes complaining about read-only filesystem and that's all that's visible.

To reiterate, I can't look through `/var/log` because the filesystem has been mounted read-only by then, so `rsyslog` failed to record any errors at all.

I also have limited ability to start new tools because the disk subsystem reports generic I/O errors at this point. Only whatever is cache resident is runnable.

The only thing I can think of is turning `/var/log` into an in-memory tmpfs and restarting `rsyslog`, waiting for the error to happen, and hope I can find it in `/var/log`. Maybe even running some standard tools like `cat`, `grep`, `less`, etc. in a loop so they'll definitely be available after the disk subsystem fails.

Is there a simpler option?

Comment: Send log to another host using rsyslog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `log_buf_len=` [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) via grub to something big like `8M`.